# How to re-use existing Joi schema properties?

Tags: javascript, node.js, joi

I have the following schema:

```js
const baseSchema = Joi.object({
  a: Joi.string().trim().empty(null, ''),
  b: Joi.string().guid().empty(null),
})
  .xor('a', 'b')
  .messages({
    'object.missing': 'One of "a", "b" is required.',
    'object.xor': 'Only one of "a", "b" is allowed.',
  });
```

I want to create another schema that includes **only the properties** of the `baseSchema` (without the 'xor' dependency and messages).

The extended schema should look like:

```js
const extendedSchema = Joi.object({
  a: Joi.string().trim().empty(null, ''),
  b: Joi.string().guid().empty(null),
  c: Joi.string().trim(),
})
  .xor('a', 'b', 'c')
  .messages({
    'object.missing': 'One of "a", "b", "c" is required.',
    'object.xor': 'Only one of "a", "b", "c" is allowed.',
  });
```

I tried using both the `keys()` and `append()` methods but these end-up duplicating the 'xor' dependency and messages as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [object.keys([schema])](https://joi.dev/api/?v=17.9.1#objectkeysschema)

```js
const baseSchema = Joi.object({
  a: Joi.string().trim().empty(null, ''),
  b: Joi.string().guid().empty(null),
});

const extendedSchema = baseSchema.keys({
    c: Joi.string().trim()
});

const firstSchema = baseSchema.xor('a', 'b')
  .messages({
    'object.missing': 'One of "a", "b" is required.',
    'object.xor': 'Only one of "a", "b" is allowed.',
  });

const secondSchema = extendedSchema.xor('a', 'b', 'c')
  .messages({
    'object.missing': 'One of "a", "b", "c" is required.',
    'object.xor': 'Only one of "a", "b", "c" is allowed.',
  });
```

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mention it. I tried that but it duplicates the dependency and messages.

Comment: I think you should add the messages and xor in a separate schema. I will edit the answer to reflect that.

Comment: Thanks! That's what I ended-up doing. I was hoping for a more elegant solution but I guess it's ok.